# search results displaying the same thing

Tags: php, sql

I have a search bar and a sql database with 3 movies in

```
Name:Star Wars: Description: Contains the word group
Name:301: Description: Contains the word group
Name:destroyer: Description: Contains the word group
```

BUT when ever I search for the word "group"

I only get one result usually:

if i search for group star wars will appear 3 time.

also i know its vulnerable to sql injection but at the moment that is not an issue

here is my php code:

```
 if(!isset($_POST['search']))
 {
   header("Location:index.php");

 }

$search_sql="SELECT * FROM php_item WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%' OR Description LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'";
$search_query = mysql_query($search_sql);
 if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=0)
 {

   $search_rs= mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
  }


 ?>


      </p>
      <p>&nbsp; Search Results</p>
      <?php

       if(mysql_num_rows($search_query) != 0){
          do{ ?>

          <p>
          <?php echo $search_rs['Name']; ?>

         <?php     }while($searchr_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));

      } else {
        echo "No Results Found";  
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: You should look into full text indexing. It really is easy to implement and adds a lot of functionality like multiple words or requiring/excluding certain words.

Comment: Could you provide a Sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables and the data? your problem is in your SQL, but is weird, because the query looks well, so it must be in other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your code, there is a typo in the `while`. It should be `$search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query)`. You have an extra 'r'.

Good Luck!

Comment: if this solved your problem, please mark it as an answer and close this question.